# zsh alias doesn't always take arguments

Tags: terminal, command-line, zsh, alias

I have the following aliases set in my zsh config:

```bash
alias artisan='[ -f vendor/bin/sail ] && sail artisan || php artisan'
alias sail='[ -f sail ] && bash sail || bash vendor/bin/sail'
alias dep='[ -f dep ] && dep || vendor/bin/dep'
```

The `sail` and `dep` aliases work as expected. For example, I can type `sail up` or `dep deploy` and the arguments (`up`, `deploy`) will be passed to the aliased command.

However, for `artisan` this is not the case. I always get the default help page that will be displayed when no argument was supplied. Why does this happen?

Comment: It probably breaks when you’re not in the “root” directory.  You’re calling a command that assumes you’re in a directory where `vendor/…` exists.  If you’re in a different  one, it will fail.

Comment: @Allan those with vendor are the two working

Comment: What do you expect the artisan alias tro be expanded to?

Comment: @mmmmmm, artisan is the only alias that specifies a path for the conditional test. . Sail and dep could be in the path which is why those work

Comment: Ah yes missed that

Comment: The title of your question is misleading: An `alias` **never** takes argument. It is just that if the command in a zsh statement is an alias, this word is replaced by the string defined in the `alias` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alias is a simple text substitution, so the command `artisan up` will be expanded to this:

```
[ -f vendor/bin/sail ] && sail artisan || php artisan up
```

The `up` is only at the end. If the `vendor/bin/sail` file exists, then the `sail artisan` command will be executed without any other parameters. If the file does not exist, the command after `||` will be run - since it's at the end, it will get `up` passed as a parameter. That's probably what happened in the situations where the alias worked.

To pass arguments to a command, you can use a function:

```bash
artisan() {
  if [ -f vendor/bin/sail ]; then
    sail artisan "$@"
  else
    php artisan "$@"
  fi
}
```

`"$@"` will expand to the parameters from the function invocation, i.e. with `artisan up` it'll pass `up` to either of the commands.

Note that this example uses an `if-else` statement.  Although `[ condition ] && cmd1 || cmd2` looks like a ternary statement, it really isn't - if the condition evaluates to true and `cmd1` exits with a non-zero return code, `cmd2` will also be executed. Most of the time that's unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thank you. Do I understand it correctly, that therefore my `sail` and `dep` aliases only worked, because there were no files called `sail` and `dep` in my current working directory, therefore it used the "fallback" with my arguments substituted to the end? Knowing that the substitution happens immediately explains a lot, but makes sense when thinking about it.

Comment: That's correct. I updated the answer to try to explain it a bit better.

Comment: Good remark about the unexpected side effects of `[ c ] && c1 || c2`. They can be avoided by using `[ c ] && { c1; true; } || c2` but using a proper `if then else` might be easier then :-)

Comment: @nohillside And in zsh `if-else` can be just as [compact](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/468597): `if [[ c ]] { c1 } else { c2 }`.